Rust でexit codeを取得する方法
rustで「前回実行したコマンドのexit code」によって分岐する処理を書きたいです。要するに環境変数の$?が取得したいです。
以下、うまくいかなかったやり方です。
use std::env;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
  // 1
  let exit_code = env::var("?");
  println!("{}", exit_code.unwrap()); // panic

  // 2
  let output = Command::new("echo").arg("$?").output().expect("failed to execute process");
  println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).trim_end()) // => $?
}

cargo run $?

のようにして
env::args().collect()

で取得することはできるのですが、可能な限り実行時に変数を渡したくないです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Rustに限らずどんな言語であっても、何かログ情報とかでもない限り、そのプログラム自身と関係無いところで実行・終了した後の情報を取得することは出来ないのでは？ その「前回実行したコマンド」を実行した後ではなく、それらのコマンドとパラメータをまとめて引数として指定してもらい、Rustで作ったプログラムの中で子プロセスとして実行して、終了結果のexit codeを取得して判断するくらいしか無いのでは？

ですよね。シェルスクリプトで書かれたコマンドをRustで置き換えていたのですが、おっしゃるとおりこの部分は実装不可能に思えてきました。

$?は環境変数ではないので、親プロセスで参照できても子プロセスには引き継がれません。
ですので、別名で環境変数として定義して該当プログラムで読み取るか(例:  env::var("example_var"))、質問文にあるように引数で明示的に渡して読み取るか、という方法になると思います。
＃なお、bashでは$?のようなものは「特殊パラメータ」と呼んでいます。(シェル変数とは区別している)

man bash
https://ja.manpages.org/bash

